# NavigationView: Mark menu as dirty

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I am using the `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`. During the lifetime of this view the menu items get changed (removed, renamed and added) dynamically. However these changes do not get displayed directly, but only after the view has been destroyed and created again (e.g. on orientation change).

Is there a way force it to update the menu?

Answer (score 1):

***Adding a dynamic menu to NavigationView is currently bug on Design Support library. And I see that the someone has been report it to android bug source tracking. So wait till the bug will fixed. But if you want the temporary solution you can do it. First add your dynamic menu ..***

```
navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navView);
Menu m = navView.getMenu();
SubMenu topChannelMenu = m.addSubMenu("Top Channels");
topChannelMenu.add("Foo");
topChannelMenu.add("Bar");
topChannelMenu.add("Baz");
```

After adding your menu just write below code ..

```
MenuItem mi = m.getItem(m.size()-1);
mi.setTitle(mi.getTitle());
```

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176300

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work in my case; I have three menus that are built from an xml, to which I add and remove items programatically. Get-setting the title as proposed did not force the submenus to be redrawn, as proposed; another solution I found was to add another temporary submenu to the navigation menu and remove it again, which unfortunately also did not help.